# Making TableView from CoreData

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using CoreData for the first time, and trying to figure out how to populate a TableView using it.  I have seen the sample code Apple provides, but get confused here:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = …; //Retrieve the main queue NSManagedObjectContext
```

How do I retrieve the main queue NSManagedObjectContext?  I've seen some say get it from AppDelegate, and I've seen others say that's not the correct way to do it, and Apple doesn't seem to use either method, and for some unknown reason just decides to omit code.

Comment: Get it from AppDelegate. As a starting point there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `NSFetchedResultsController` here is a complete tutorial that features it with tableView

Swift : [NSFetchedResultsController](https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3)

Objective-C : [NSFetchedResultsController](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-21681)  & [NSFetchedResultsController](https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Comment: Is there any version of that in Obj-C?